# FileOutputStream error, exists() cannot find symbol

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

Hi I'm trying to save a file using the FileOutputStream but it always gives me the FileNotFoundException.

```
    public void savefile(Object myObject) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("c:/Something.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream fOUT = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        fOUT.writeObject(myObject);  
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

This is the code, I already tried to use this:

```
            if(!f.exists()){
            f.createNewFile();
        }
```

But it says "Cannot find symbol"

Am I missing something?

Comment: try printing the value returned from createNewFile method call.

Comment: If `f` is a `FileOutputStream` you cannot apply `exists` or `createNewFile`. These are methods of `File`, which I don't see in your code.

Comment: You should not need to use `f.createNewFile()` at all... the file will automatically get created when the FileOutputStream is written to.

Comment: @SMA could you be more specific?

Comment: Check: **You don't have permission to write into C:\**

Answer (score 1):

By default its not possible to write to `c:\` under Windows. Try using a different path

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/Something.txt");
```

Comment: You should not need to use f.createNewFile() at all... the file will automatically get created when the FileOutputStream is written to.

Comment: Agreed. It's probably bad style to write to `c:\ ` directly anyway... `new FileOutputStream("something.txt")` is probably the best choice. It will write to the directory the program is running in, which is probably what the op wanted in the first place...

Comment: @Reimeus well, I tried another path...it always gives me the error but the file is created and it's all messed up :s

Comment: @Leandro what do you mean the file is all messed up? You are writing a serialized object to the file, so you would not be able to view the data in a text editor...

Comment: @RudolphEst sorry if I can't explain properly my problem, I'm an Italian student and I'm trying to learn Java :s

I'm trying to save an array in order to not lose the "things" I wrote in the array, so...how am I supposed to save the file in order to "use" it again using the "read" method?

Comment: @Leandro `ObjectOutputStream` is for writing binary data. You need `BufferedWriter` or `PrintWriter` for text files

Comment: @Leandro there are two ways to write datato files. Binary data and character data. Binary data can be read by computers but not by humans. The way you are using looks fine if you don't want a human to read the data. You can find details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Comment: @Leandro Perhaps you describe what kind of array you need to save. Right now you have an Object that needs to be written, which may be too general.

Comment: @laune I'm trying to save an array of Users of a bank. Their name, their checking account, their money etc.

Comment: I'm using a Swing GUI Form and I've already created the jButton which creates my array of Users and puts the data of the user in the array and now I'm trying to create a Button which saves this array and another batton which reads this array

Comment: @Leandro Unless you need to read the file using wordpad etc, using a DataOutputStream might indeed be a good idea. Otherwise you'll have to: a) design a text (!) representation of a User's data, b) implement a User.toString(), c) write the file, User by User, d) implement another method that can read a User's textual data as you wrote it, etc. You get the idea?

Comment: @laune I've already created an User.toString and created a method which reads the file I want to save

`public Object read() {
        Object myObject = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("file");
            ObjectInputStream fIN = new ObjectInputStream(f);
            myObject = fIN.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return myObject;
    }`

Comment: @Leandro So you stick with ObjectInput/OutputStream and don't use toString(). IMHO, preferable.

Answer (score -2):

On windows paths usually include backslashes

```
\
```

not frontslashes (those are used in UNIX systems).

```
/
```

Please try if the following works:

```
public void savefile(Object myObject) {
try {
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Something.txt");
ObjectOutputStream fOUT = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
fOUT.writeObject(myObject);  
f.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
}
```

Comment: This actually does not matter on newer versions of java (1.4 onwards I think). Either `c:\\something.txt` or `c:/something.txt` should work.

Comment: Who said that it's Windows, and do you really think that the problem lies there? Using slash instead of backslash is a safe bet. You've basically only rewritten the code from the question (and with bad formatting) and made it run only on Windows.

Comment: @RudolphEst Are you saying that backslash will work on non-Windows platforms?

Comment: @afterfox I am saying that either ` \\ ` or ` / ` in file paths in Windows is equivalent, so if one works, both would work.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you really want:

```
try {
    File thatFile = new File('c:/something.txt')
    if (thatFile.exists()) {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(thatFile);
        ObjectOutputStream fOUT = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        fOUT.writeObject(myObject);  
            f.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Every file does not exist before it is written the first time. Your code will actually prevent the exception *and writing of any file that hasn't been written before.*

Comment: The problem is that the file is not created automatically, not that the poster only want's to write to it if it already exists.